# Type casting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, types, casting

What is the proper way to cast data types in Matlab?

I have my data stream (instrument data) as undifferentiated elements of a uint8 array, which I want to cast into a composite data types, like for instance a 3-byte, 24-bit integer, or a 3-byte, 3 character string.

I normally do this on the fly specifying a format in fread(), but once the data is already in a uint8 array, is typecast() the proper way to go about it, or is there a nicer syntax?

Comment: check out [this page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there is not any data type for integer 3 or 24 bytes (see [documentaion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html)). However, about casting from uint8 to string, it can be done by `num2str` function (like `num2str(uint8(123))`. Also if you want get a 2 char string (from left) you can do it by `num2str(uint8(123))(end-1:end)`;